# Find which database was affected when database not found?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have executed a query from .sql file in SSMS which starts with the **"USE"** query:

```
use mydatabase
Go
```

However there was a typo in **mydatabase**. it was **myddatabase** and I received the following error:

> Database '**myddatabase**' does not exist. Make sure that the name is
> entered correctly.

After that there are a lot of successsful `insert` queries with the following message:

> (1 row affected)

So I am afraid if those queries where executed on another database. How can I find which database was affected? Is there a default database?

Comment: Check each database for the table you inserted to. The table must exist for the inserts to succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have updated database that was active before `USE` statement.

That means if `master` database was active and you write statement for example

```
USE myddatabase
```

and this statement produce an error all lines below after `GO` are executed in the `master`.

You can easily see always which database is active at the bottom right corner of your `SSMS`.

[image]

Comment: Yes! the master database was exploded! What heppens then? :))

Comment: You have create probably all tables, views or whatever and then inserted data in these tables. Go to in your SSMS expand Database directory then System database and then master. You have will find everything you create there.

Comment: Yes there was tables I crated in my query. Isn't the master database the moderator of other databases? There are only the created tables in master database now but how other databases are still working fine?

Comment: The master database stored primary configuration of your SQL Server, but that doesn't not prevent you to create on that database whatever you want even is that not good practice, you can create some tracking tables, command logs etc.